# KeyError: 0 while iterating over keys of a dictionary in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I want to delete the person of each team with the least score. But I always got an KeyError: 0

```
Players = {'An': {'Team ':'Red','Score':6 }, 'Jef': {'Team':'Blue','Score': 7 },'Jos': {'Team':'Red','Score':5 }}
names= Players.keys()
for i in range (len(names)):
      if Players[i]["Team"] == Players[i+1]["Team"] :
          if Players[i]['Score'] > PLayers[i+1]['Score']:
            Players.remove(Players[i+1])
```

Has anyone an idea which mistake I make? (For the record,I know this code is inefficient as hell, but for this project I can't use most Python tools or a list comprehension for example )

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? This is clearly an XY problem

Comment: `names = Player.keys()` will return a list consist of 3 elements. and naturally len(names) will be 3. so, `for i in range (len(names)):` is equivalent of `for i in range(3)`.  this expression will assign i values 0,1,2. and in the next line, you make a conditional statement `if Player[i]... ` this could be `Player[0]`, `Player[1]` or `Player[2]`. write last ones to python interpreter and observe results. 

your keys are 'An', `Jef` and `Jos`, not 0,1,2. try iterating over valid/existing keys. `for i in names: ...`

Answer (score 2):

You should do something as this:

```
Players = {'An': {'Team':'Red','Score':6 }, 'Jef': {'Team':'Blue','Score':7 },'Jos': {'Team':'Red','Score':5 }}
names = Players.keys()
player_to_remove = []
for i in range(0, len(names) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(names)):
        if Players[names[i]]['Team'] == Players[names[j]]['Team'] :
            if Players[names[i]]['Score'] < Players[names[j]]['Score']:
                player_to_remove.append(names[i])
            if Players[names[i]]['Score'] > Players[names[j]]['Score']:
                player_to_remove.append(names[j])
for key in player_to_remove:
    del Players[key]
```

The print our of Players is:
{'Jef': {'Score': 7, 'Team': 'Blue'}, 'An': {'Score': 6, 'Team': 'Red'}}
Joe has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

`for i in range(len(names))` does `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`

`Players` doesn't have any of those keys.

Not to mention you're trying to create some kind of an order in a dictionary, which is *by definition* an orderless data structure. Down this road lies madness.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are looping by index, which is not there with dictionaries. You need to loop by keys and then do whatever processing you want to do.

```
for pname, pinfo in Players.iteritems()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first `for` loop, the index is an integer. Then, you're trying to access `Players[i]`: is impossible, because the keys of `Players` are only strings. In particular, calling Players[0] leads to an error: the '0' key doesn't exist. The KeyError comes from this.

Instead, you should use `for key in Players.keys():`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have specified key in those dictionary.

```
Players = {'An': {'Team ':'Red','Score':6 }, 'Jef': {'Team':'Blue','Score': 7 },'Jos': {'Team':'Red','Score':5 }}
names= Players.keys()
for i in range (len(names)): # range will give you the integer, not the key in Players dict.
      if Players[i]["Team"] == Players[i+1]["Team"] : # eg: for 1st loop you will get Players[0]["Team"] is not present in Players dict, will throw the key error.
          if Players[i]['Score'] > PLayers[i+1]['Score']:
            Players.remove(Players[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to index the dict `Players` as if it were a list. Use:

`for player in Players:`

Also please do not capitalize `Players` since it makes it look like a class.